# How set formControl valid when i have at least one element inside?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have one `formGroup` that have an array:

```
createForm() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [[], [Validators.required]]      
   })
}
```

I have a list of checkbox that when it is checked, i add in this array the value, but when i do `console.log(form.controls('name').valid)` it returns `false` but i have elements in this `formControl`:

```
<mat-list-item *ngFor="let name of myNames">
   <mat-checkbox (click)="addItemInArray(name.id)">{{ name.name }}</mat-checkbox>
</mat-list-item>

addItemInArray(id: number) {
   const indexElem = this.form.get('name').value.indexOf(id);
   if (indexElem === -1) {
      this.form.get('name').value.push(id)
   } else {
      this.form.get('name').value.splice(indexElem, 1)
}
```

I'm looking if there's a way to make this control valid when i have at least one element inside the array.

Comment: what do you think do the same with `formArray`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use `Validators.minLength(1)`. According to the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#minLength):

> Note that the minLength validator is intended to be used only for types that have a numeric length property, such as strings or arrays.

```
createForm() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: [[], [Validators.minLength(1)]]      
   })
}
```

Second thing, you need to use `.setValue()` to set the value or call `.updateValueAndValidity()` after appending the value. The validator won't be aware that the array is changed because it is keeping the same object reference. Personally, I will choose the first, because I hate mutable arrays. You can try something like the following:

```
const control = this.form.get('name');
const control.setValue([...control.value, theNewValue]);
```

Comment: I tried with minLength but it is starting with valid "true" but i don't have elements inside the array

Comment: Consider creating a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators). It should be fairly simple. Try to leverage reactive forms features. It pays off more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example with the formArray, but I like @Aboodz's answer too.

**In Component**

```js
get nameArray() {
  return this.form.get('name') as FormArray;  // 
}

createForm() {
   this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: this.formBuilder.array([], [Validators.required])   
   })
}

addItemInArray(id: number) {
   const indexElem = this.findItemIndex(id);
   if (indexElem === -1) {
     this.nameArray.push(this.formBuilder.control(id));
   } else {
     this.nameArray.removeAt(indexElem)
}

findItemIndex(id: number) {
  return this.nameArray.controls.findIndex(control => control.value === id);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Please check the Stackblitz example: https://angular-forms-formarray-example-uwp9tm.stackblitz.io

I have created the simple example, and add a console where I am printing the `FormArray` value

Comment: I'm trying this way, how i can catch all the nameArray values? I need these in only one array

Comment: @veroneseComS it is one array you can get the value by this way: `this. nameArray.getRawValue()`.

Comment: @veroneseComS strange. It should work. can you share some screenshots or code example?

Comment: @veroneseComS I have created simple Stackblitz example. Please check it.